# Sitecore helix project is not copying files from nuget package with content

Tags: nuget, sitecore

I have a nuget package that has code, view and some TDS content. I am trying to install this package in a sitecore project that follows helix pattern.
My target is to copy the views inside views folder, update packages inside App_Data/somefolder/.. when installing the package.

but it is not doing that at all. Even though I have the right files inside the "content" folder in the package.

but if I install the same nuget in a project that does not follow helix pattern, it just copies the files in the desired target.

this is from the nuspec file.

```
<contentFiles>
  <files include="any/any/Views/myfolder/myview.cshtml" buildAction="Content" />
  <files include="any/any/App_Data/Mypackage.Master.scitems.update" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
  <files include="any/any/App_Data/Mypackage.Core.scitems.update" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
  <files include="any/any/App_Data/Mypackage.Content.scitems.update" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
</contentFiles>
```

so I am not sure what to do in this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
The nuget package has TDS. It is a class library and
"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" type.

The Project I am trying the nuget package to install on is a web project and uses PackageReference for the nuget.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this. Could you elaborate a bit more on what your project setup looks like and how it's being built? You mention TDS. Do you let TDS deploy your files to the target folder or do you use something else? What Project type are you using? Is the project referencing the nuget package a web project or just a library? Are you using .Net SDK csproj style or the classic one? What content ends up in the the TDS build folders?

Comment: @mikaelnet I have added few more details in the question.